# Using C functions with ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, calling-convention

I have seen examples of people using printf from the C library in their code like so:

```
.data
.balign 4
hello: .asciz "Hello\n"

.text
.global main
.func main

main:
    ldr r0, hello_msg
    bl printf
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0
hello_msg: .word hello
.global printf
```

How did they figure out r0 would be passed as a string arg to printf? I know r0-r3 are passed as args whenever a subroutine is called, but I don't know which register maps to which arg. Example: when using scanf, r0 is the string formatting and r1 stores the user input. How are we supposed to know this? My only guess is to compile my *.s file with gcc using the -S option and viewing the assembled file... but is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you read up on the ABI that the C library uses...

Comment: I have already looked at the [ABI for ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0371l/DUI0371L_mxscript-v1-3-for-fast-models_reference-manual.pdf) and it doesn't mention anything about registers. Also, it was the only C Library ABI I could find. Where do I find ABIs that specify how each register is used?

Comment: It is part of the eabi or abi for arm.  maybe you are not looking at the right one/place.  At the end of the day the compiler is right if nothing else as far as talking to itself so generate a simple C function, call it from another simple C function and for that compiler what registers it chooses are the right ones.  Now when you start doing things like 64 bit variables or floating point the register/stack usage can become non-linear (they might skip r1 or r3 for example).  Just re-prototype and mimic.

Comment: for arm it has far as long as I know, r0 is the first parameter r1 the second and so on (again using normal small fits in one general purpose register things) and then after r3 it goes to the stack.   so fun(a,b,c,d) if those are all 32 bit, 16 or 8 bit pass by value then r0 = a, r1=b, and so on.  if you make b a 64 bit integer though it might skip  r1 and use r2/r3 for b then C and D on the stack.  But you would have to try it to find out.

Comment: if using soft float vs hard float then obviously soft float is going to use general purpose registers to move stuff around where hard float may(should?) use floating point registers.   Takes longer to write the question above than to just try it and see what the compiler produces.

Comment: No idea what scripting Fast Models has to do with anything, but the relevant part of the ARM EABI (assuming you're not on some ancient or esoteric system) would be the [Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/index.html), which is definitely about registers (where it's not about data types). Note that EABI has platform-specific aspects, but assuming you're on Linux it's probably safe at this level to not worry about the specific details of the GNU variant (I'm not even sure I know them off-hand, other than r9 having no special purpose).

Comment: This blog post is taking about ARM on iOS, but the information is general enough to be useful for any ARM ASM development: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post10_arm_timing_framework

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain what I have learned. The only Linux that I have is Raspbian Jessie (Raspberry Pi 3). There is a file /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/unistd.h (other Linux should have unistd.h somewhere) that shows define for functions build into Linux [ex: #define __NR_write (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+  4)]. Look at Linux Man Page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/write.3p.html at the format.

```
     ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)
return in r0  [4] (      r0  ,            r1  ,       r2    )
```

I am kind of new at this, so I have included a program that helps me understand it. Also see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_by_project.html#man-pages for other formats.

```
@----------------------------------
@ asfileio.s
@
@ Raspbian Jessie assembly program using
@ SVC for file operations on Raspberry Pi 3
@
@ pi@RPi:~/Programs $ as -o asfileio.o asfileio.s
@ pi@RPi:~/Programs $ gcc -o asfileio asfileio.o
@ pi@RPi:~/Programs $ ./asfileio; echo $?; ls -l /tmp/test*
@ Hello world
@ A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
@ 0
@ -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 26 Jun 18 14:58 /tmp/testfile01.txt
@ -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 45 Jun 18 14:58 /tmp/testfile02.txt
@ pi@RPi:~/Programs $
@----------------------------------
@
@ http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_by_project.html#man-pages
@
@  CREATE int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
@             Mode  rwx {owner, group, other}
@  OPEN   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
@             Flags  O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR
@                    | O_APPEND
@  READ   ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
@  WRITE  ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
@  CLOSE  int close(int fd);
@  SYNC   void sync(void);
@  EXIT   void _Exit(int status);
@
@----------------------------------

.data

@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/unistd.h
@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/fcntl-linux.h

    .equ create,     8
         .equ Mode, 0644       @ -rw-r--r--
    .equ open,       5
         .equ Rd,   00
         .equ Wr,   01
         .equ RdWr, 02
         .equ Apnd, 02000
    .equ read,       3
    .equ write,      4
    .equ close,      6
    .equ sync,       36
    .equ exit,       1
    .equ sfile,      187

@----------------------------------

.balign 4
Create:
    .word dir_file, Mode, create 

.balign 4
Open:
    .word dir_file, RdWr | Apnd, open

.balign 4
Write:
    .word  data, after_data - data, write

.balign 4
Write2:
    .word  data2, after_data2 - data2, write

.balign 4
Read:
    .word Buf, 80, read
.balign 4
Buf:
    .space 80

@----------------------------------

data:
 .asciz "Hello world\n"
after_data:

.balign 4
data2:
 .asciz "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"
after_data2:

.balign 4
dir_file:
 .asciz "/tmp/testfile01.txt"

@----------------------------------

.text

.global main, _start

@_start:                       @ Uncommit if using ld as linker
main:

      push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
      b      M_Program

S_Write:     @ err 4 if error  @ subroutine or function
@ System call to write to file (or stdout)
@ Write  amt_wrote=(write( fd,    &data, sizeof(data)))
@               r0=(r7=4(  r0, r1=&data, r2=len(data)))

      ldr    r3, =Write        @ address of parameters
S_Write2:
      ldm    r3, {r1, r2, r7}  @ load write parameters
      svc    #0                @ Linux kernel writes
      cmp    r0, r2            @ check amt = len
      movne  r0, #4            @ set error code to 4
      bne    exit              @ exit if error
      mov    r0, #0            @ success
      mov    pc, lr            @ return to program

S_Create:    @ err 8 if error  
@ Create  fd=(creat(   &dir_file, -rw-r--r--))
@         r0=(r7=8 (r0=&dir_file,   r1=0644 ))

      ldr    r3, =Create
      ldm    r3, {r0, r1, r7}
      svc    #0
      mov    r4, r0            @ save fd in r4
      cmp    r0, #3            @ err if < 3
      movlt  r0, #8
      blt    exit
      mov    r0, #0
      mov    pc, lr

S_Open:      @ err 5 if error

      ldr    r3, =Open
      ldm    r3, {r0, r1, r7}
      svc    #0
      mov    r4, r0
      cmp    r0, #3
      movlt  r0, #5
      blt    exit
      mov    r0, #0
      mov    pc, lr

S_Close:     @ err 6 if error

      mov    r7, #close
      svc    #0
      cmp    r0, #0
      movne  r0, #6
      bne    exit
      mov    pc, lr

S_Read:

      ldr    r3, =Read
      ldm    r3, {r1, r2, r7}
      svc    #0
      mov    pc, lr

M_Program:

@ S_Write call to write to stdout

      mov    r0, #1            @ fd=1=stdout
      bl     S_Write

@ Create, write and close file in /tmp

      bl     S_Create          @ create file
      mov    r0, r4            @ move fd to r0
      bl     S_Write           @ write to file
      mov    r0, r4            @ move fd to r0
      bl     S_Close           @ close the file

@ Open same file for write append

      bl     S_Open            @ open file
      mov    r0, r4            @ move fd to r0
      bl     S_Write           @ write to file
      mov    r0, r4            @ move fd to r0
      bl     S_Close           @ close file

@ Change variables for new file

      ldr    r3, =dir_file
      add    r3, #12
      ldr    r2, [r3]
      eor    r2, #0x30000
      str    r2, [r3]

@ Create new file, write and close

      bl     S_Create
      mov    r0, r4
      ldr    r3, =Write2
      bl     S_Write2
      mov    r0, r4
      bl     S_Close

@ Open file, read, write to stdout and close

     bl      S_Open
     mov     r0, r4
     bl      S_Read

     mov     r2, r0            @ r0 has amt read
     mov     r0, #1            @ fd = 1 = stdout
     ldr     r1, =Buf          @ addr data just read
     mov     r7, #write
     svc     #0
     mov     r0, r4
     bl      S_Close

exit:

      pop    {r4, r5, r7, lr}
      bx     lr                @ Exit if use gcc as linker
@     mov    r7, #1            @ Exit if use ld as linker
@     svc    #0                @ Exit if use ld as linker
```

The best docs that I have found on arm registers are http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/656023/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf page 14.