# segmentation fault at every assembly code

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I'am trying to learn assemly on raspberry pi.But I couldn't get started, every code i write gets "Segmentation Fault".

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
   MOV R0, #2
   SWI 0
```

This code gets segmentation fault. Even if I delete the MOV line it gets segmentation fault.

Comment: How do you assemble and run the code?

Comment: as -o ams1.o asm1.s "enter"
ld -o asm1 asm1.o "enter"
./asm1 "enter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
bx   lr                   @ Exit if use gcc as linker
```

or

```
mov  r7, #1               @ Exit if use ld as linker
svc  #0                   @ Exit if use ld as linker
```

Some version use `swi`, I have success with `svc` using `ld` as the linker. If you use `gcc` as the linker, the `lr` register has the return to OS. Be sure to save the lr register at the beginning of your code and restore it before the `bx lr`. See [Using C functions with ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311411/using-c-functions-with-arm-assembly/38315228#38315228) for more details.

Comment: When you say "use gcc as linker", do you mean writing `main` in asm so you can return to the CRT startup code that called it?  Or do you mean that `gcc -static -nostdlib` to just link your `.o` into an executable is different from using `ld`?

Comment: It has been a year since I was involved in assembly. My example was `as -o asfileio.o asfileio.s` and then link with `gcc -o asfileio asfileio.o`. There may be a single step to assemble and link in one step, I don't remember. See the link in my answer above. That was the way that I did it.

Comment: A simple example of using gcc as linker would be http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/.

Answer (score 3):

In the EABI that the Raspberry Pi uses, `SWI 0` is just the system call entry. You still need to specify which function you want using `r7`. So, something like this should work:

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
   MOV R0, #2
   MOV R7, #1 ; sys_exit
   SWI 0
```

Comment: asm1.s: Assembler messages:
asm1.s:5: Error: bad instruction `sys_exit'   I am getting that error.

Comment: Presumably your assembler doesn't use semicolon for comment. You may remove the `; sys_exit` of course, or use whatever is appropriate for your assembler. The important thing is to load `r7` with `1`.

Comment: Use a debugger then to see why it faults. My guess is, on your machine `sys_exit` might not be `#1` and it returns, continuing into uninitialized memory.