# ARM assembly: stdin, stdout, registers and programme/OS interaction

Tags: assembly, arm, stdout, stdin

This is for assembly for Raspberry Pi.
I am not sure if I understand how the registers, when used by a programme, interact with the operating system, nor how the keyboard buffer works in relation to a programme wanting access to an input string.
I have included an example with an attempt at an explanation, in order to try to convey my current understanding (misguided, or lack thereof); this example used stdin and stdout with read and write:

```
@receive input via stdin (keyboard)
ldr R1,=msg @address to receive input
mov R2,#20 @maximum number of characters to receive
mov R0,#0 @stdin
mov R7,#3 @read
svc 0 @call linux
```

So this asks linux to read from stdin. R0 and R7 specify stdin and that the programme wants to read, svc 0 then asks linux to do this. I am not sure why R2 holds the "maximum number of characters" value - the comments are mine, but are based on other examples I have seen, which seem to have this "maximum character" part -. I assume R1 will hold the address of where the message will be stored (transferred from the keyboard buffer?). The next few lines of code are:

```
@echo output, one character at a time, with a newline after each character
    mov R4,R0 @number of characters input
    mov R5,R0 @copy to test for input
    mov R2,#1 @display one character at a time
    mov R0,#1 @stdout
    mov R7,#4 @write
inloop: swi 0 @call linux
    add R3,R1,#1 @save address of next byte to be displayed
    ldr R1,=newln @character skips to newline
    swi 0 @call linux
    mov R1,R3 @restore pointer to message being displayed
    subs R4,#1 @decrement number of characters remaining
    bgt inloop @continue loop until message complete

    .data
msg: .ds 10 @memory buffer for keyboard input
newln: .ascii "\n" @newline character
```

R0, which was previously set to inform linux that I wanted to use stdin, now contains an integer specifying the number of characters entered (including newline). R2, which previously contained an integer value specifying - I think - the maximum number of characters that could be accepted, now seems to specify how many characters are to be written.

R0 is now used to indicate stdout, and R7 specifies write, then svc 0 calls linux. R3 is R1+1; therefore, I assume this means that R1 is the address of the first character received from the input, and R3 will point to the next character. R1 switches to point to the newline character, linux is called to write, and R1 switches back to point to the message, but at the second character (since it receives the data from R3). The loop then continues if there are more characters available (R4 is acting as a conventional counter, here).

It seems to be the case that certain registers perform certain roles when interacting with the operating system. Certain registers can be the "active component": they can ask linux to do certain things, such as read or write, using stdin and stdout. For example, they can be assigned integer values, which are then used by a service call to identify what the service call has to do; e.g. setting the (specific) registers 0 and 7 to 0 and 3, respectively, tells linux that the program wants to read from stdin. When reading, R2 seems to specify the number of characters that can be accepted, and R1 is a pointer to where the characters should be stored. When writing, R2 tells linux how many characters to write, whilst R1 is the pointer to the first character (although not necessarily the first character in a string).

Registers can also be the "passive component": receiving input from linux. For example, once the call to read has been made, R0 then contains an integer value identifying the number of characters received from stdin.

Is this in anyway accurate? I am also confused about how stdin works: there seems to be a keyboard buffer, but the string is transferred somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, registers are used to pass arguments to the operating system during a system call. As to what they are, you must consult the documentation, e.g. [man 2 write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: @Jay Lin, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311411/using-c-functions-with-arm-assembly/38315228#38315228 for my understanding of Arm  assembly and Linux.

Comment: Hi thanks for thee feedback. Is there any way I can accept your replies?